# c# excel image

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, vsto, excel-2007

hi i have inserted image on an excel worksheet...

how is it possible to refer to this image from c#, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use the Clipboard object and the Excel Interop assembly.  See [here](http://joymonscode.blogspot.com/2009/01/reading-image-from-excel-file.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this: either start excel and get the image via the api, or open the excel file directly using the open xml format. I would recomend the latter. See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338205.aspx

for details on the format.