# how to insert a jpeg image into an excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel

I'm able to generate tables with all the required columns and with data from an Excel sheet. Now I want to insert an image that is present in my bin.  How could I achieve this?

Answer (score -2):

Look here:
[c# excel image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133892/c-excel-image)

Paste image through clipboard.

Comment: He wants to use an image in his bin folder, not the clipboard.